# pg_dump [archiver (db)] query failed, permission denied, even after I granted those

Tags: postgresql

I was following this web page:

http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2008/03/mysql-versus-postgresql-adding-an-auto-increment-column-to-a-table.html

In order to make an auto increment.
But the sequence I had to make is now messing with my pg_dump, when I try this standard one :

`pg_dump -f /home/admin/db_backup/dump_date.sql -Ox -U username -h localhost db_name`

Here is the error I have :

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation djangocms_showroom_projectcategory_position_seq
>
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT sequence_name, start_value, increment_by, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND max_value = 9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND max_value = -1 THEN NULL      ELSE max_value END AS max_value, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND min_value = 1 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND min_value = -9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      ELSE min_value END AS min_value, cache_value, is_cycled FROM djangocms_showroom_projectcategory_position_seq

So I tried to the owner of the sequence :

`ALTER SEQUENCE djangocms_showroom_projectcategory_position_seq OWNED BY none;`

Grant all privilegies to the link table :

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE djangocms_blog_blogcategory TO username;`

But it still won't make it.

Does anyone encounter this problem before ?